# Match sqlAlchemy many-to-many query to ALL in list

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two classes joined by a many to many relationship:

```
Parent
Driver
```

You'd query it like this:

```
DBSession.query(Parent).first().drivers  #etc
```

I need a query in pseudo-code below but do not know how to construct it:

```
DBSession.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id ==1).filter(Parent.drivers.id LIST MATCHES [3, 5, 1]).all()
```

That is, we can get a list of all drivers that Parent 1 has. Then we need to see if a list, `[3, 5, 1]`, contains ALL of the IDs which are in `Parent.drivers`. Either list may not necessarily be in order.

How does one query this in sqlAlchemy?

Comment: How would you query this in SQL?

Comment: I don't know how one would do that either.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349832/sqlalchemy-filter-to-match-all-instead-of-any-values-in-list/21104689). It deals with a one-to-many relationship, which requires a slight adjustment, but it should be the same idea.

Comment: That was it- thank you.