# SQLAlchemy ORM: Filter by multiple include/exclude matches on many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I'm trying to use an SQLite database via SQLAlchemy 1.4 ORM to filter data based on relationships.

#### Data

My example data consists of groups and members in a simple many-to-many schema:

```py
[...]
member_f = Member(name="F")

group_1 = Group(name="1", members=[member_a, member_b, member_c])  <-- find this group via member names
group_2 = Group(name="2", members=[member_a, member_b, member_f])
group_3 = Group(name="3", members=[member_a, member_c, member_d])
group_4 = Group(name="4", members=[member_d, member_e, member_f])
[...]
```

Full running example code (schema, objects, queries):

```js
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, func, text, and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base, sessionmaker


engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", future=True, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, future=True)


# Schema

Base = declarative_base()


groups_members = Table("groups_members", Base.metadata,
    Column("group_id", ForeignKey("groups.id")),
    Column("member_name", ForeignKey("members.name")),
)


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    members = relationship("Member", secondary=groups_members, backref="groups", lazy="subquery")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Group: {self.name}>"


class Member(Base):
    __tablename__ = "members"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Member: {self.name}>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


# Objects

member_a = Member(name="A")
member_b = Member(name="B")
member_c = Member(name="C")
member_d = Member(name="D")
member_e = Member(name="E")
member_f = Member(name="F")

group_1 = Group(name="1", members=[member_a, member_b, member_c])
group_2 = Group(name="2", members=[member_a, member_b, member_f])
group_3 = Group(name="3", members=[member_a, member_c, member_d])
group_4 = Group(name="4", members=[member_d, member_e, member_f])

print(f"{member_a}: {member_a.groups}")  # OK

with Session() as session:
    session.add(group_1)
    session.add(group_2)
    session.add(group_3)
    session.add(group_4)

    session.commit()

    print(session.query(Group).all())  # OK


# Query users example

def get_members_in_more_than_2_groups():
    with Session() as session:
        return session.execute(
            select(Member, func.count(groups_members.columns.group_id).label('group_members_count'))
            .join(groups_members)
            .group_by(Member.name)
            .having(text('group_members_count > 2'))
        ).all()


for m in get_members_in_more_than_2_groups():
    print(m)  # OK


# Query groups problem: associated with A and B but not with E or F

def get_groups_by_member_names(member_names_included, member_names_excluded):
    with Session() as session:
        included = session.execute(select(Member).where(Member.name.in_(member_names_included))).all()
        excluded = session.execute(select(Member).where(Member.name.in_(member_names_excluded))).all()

        return session.execute(
            select(Group)
            .join(Group.members)
            .where(
                and_(
                    Group.members.contains(included),
                    ~Group.members.contains(excluded),
                )
            )
            .group_by(Group.id)
        ).scalars().all()


for g in get_groups_by_member_names(member_names_included=["A", "B"], member_names_excluded=["E", "F"]):
    print(g)  # Expected output: <Group: 1>
```

#### Goal

Now I'm trying to find all groups that

- have both members with the names `A` and `B` (that's groups `1` and `2`)
- and don't have any member named `E` or `F` (removing group `2`)

resulting in just group `1`.

#### Problem

The relevant (and failing) function in the example code is `get_groups_by_member_names` and with my lack of database knowledge, I'm quite stuck.

Most existing questions that I could find on SO only need to filter by one relationship value. But I need them to consider the lists of included and excluded member names.

I have tried to get the members as SQLAlchemy objects first and inserting those into the query but without any luck. I may have done that completely wrong, though.
I also tried joining the tables, filtering with the names list and counting the grouped results... It's hard for me to tell whether I'm on the right track or not at all.
Running over all groups in Python and applying the filtering there would be my fallback workaround. But with many items, the database can probably handle it more efficiently.

Any help greatly appreciated, I am happy with anything that works. I could probably also work my way up from a functioning SQL statement.

Thanks for your time!

---

#### Edit 1:

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104689/5123171 and while it works on small data sets, it's terribly slow on larger ones (about 60 seconds for 500 members and 10k groups):

```py
def get_group_by_members(member_names_included, member_names_excluded):
    with Session() as session:
        return session.query(Group).join(groups_members).filter(
            groups_members.columns.member_name.in_(member_names_included)).group_by(Group.id).having(func.count(groups_members.columns.member_name) == len(member_names_included),
        ).filter(
            ~Group.members.any(Member.name.in_(member_names_excluded)),
        ).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I ended up with via trial & error in an SQL editor. This is faster than the previous attempt (50 milliseconds on the same data).

The comments in the code correspond to the following steps:

1. Find groups containing excluded members
2. Filter those out of the assignment table
3. Filter remaining assignment table by included members
4. Group by group IDs
5. Return all remaining groups matching the number of included members

#### SQL

```sql
SELECT * FROM groups
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT group_id FROM groups_members
    WHERE member_name IN ("A", "B")                                     // 3.
    AND group_id NOT IN (                                               // 2
        SELECT group_id FROM groups_members
        WHERE member_name IN ("E", "F")                                 // 1.
    )
    GROUP BY group_id                                                   // 4.
    HAVING count(member_name) == 2                                      // 5.
)
```

#### SQLAlchemy

```py
session.query(Group)
.where(Group.id.in_(
    session.query(groups_members.c.group_id)
    .where(
        groups_members.c.member_name.in_(member_names_included),         # 3.
        groups_members.c.group_id.not_in(                                # 2.
            session.query(groups_members.c.group_id).where(
                groups_members.c.member_name.in_(member_names_excluded)  # 1.
            )
        ),
    )
    .group_by(groups_members.c.group_id)                                 # 4.
    .having(
        func.count(groups_members.c.member_name)
        == len(member_names_included)                                    # 5.
    ))
)
.all()
```

And the full running example in one piece:

```js
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, func, text, and_, not_
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base, sessionmaker


engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", future=True, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, future=True)


# Schema

Base = declarative_base()


groups_members = Table(
    "groups_members",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("group_id", ForeignKey("groups.id")),
    Column("member_name", ForeignKey("members.name")),
)


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    members = relationship(
        "Member", secondary=groups_members, backref="groups", lazy="subquery"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Group {self.id}: {self.name}>"


class Member(Base):
    __tablename__ = "members"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Member: {self.name}>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


# Objects

member_a = Member(name="A")
member_b = Member(name="B")
member_c = Member(name="C")
member_d = Member(name="D")
member_e = Member(name="E")
member_f = Member(name="F")

group_1 = Group(name="1", members=[member_a, member_b, member_c])
group_2 = Group(name="2", members=[member_a, member_b, member_f])
group_3 = Group(name="3", members=[member_a, member_c, member_d])
group_4 = Group(name="4", members=[member_d, member_e, member_f])

with Session() as session:
    session.add(group_1)
    session.add(group_2)
    session.add(group_3)
    session.add(group_4)

    session.commit()


# Query

member_names_included = ["A", "B"]
member_names_excluded = ["E", "F"]

# Raw SQL variant

with Session() as session:
    result = session.execute(
        f"""
            SELECT * FROM groups
            WHERE id IN (
                SELECT group_id FROM groups_members
                WHERE member_name IN ("A", "B")
                AND group_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT group_id FROM groups_members
                    WHERE member_name IN ("E", "F")
                )
                GROUP BY group_id
                HAVING count(member_name) == 2
            )
    """
    ).all()

    groups = [Group(**r) for r in result]

    for r in groups:
        print(f'SQL {r}')


# ORM Variant

with Session() as session:
    result = (
        session.query(Group)
        .where(
            Group.id.in_(
                session.query(groups_members.c.group_id)
                .where(
                    # Matching any included members
                    groups_members.c.member_name.in_(member_names_included),
                    # Removing any groups containing excluded members
                    groups_members.c.group_id.not_in(
                        session.query(groups_members.c.group_id).where(
                            groups_members.c.member_name.in_(member_names_excluded)
                        )
                    ),
                )
                # This is to make sure that all included members exist in a group, not just a few
                .group_by(groups_members.c.group_id)
                .having(
                    func.count(groups_members.c.member_name)
                    == len(member_names_included)
                )
            )
        )
        .all()
    )

    for r in result:
        print(f'ORM {r}')
```

I hope this is helpful to anyone and if you have suggestions for improvement, please let me know.