# Filtering in SQLAlchemy with Lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to filter in SQLAlchemy some posts. They can have multiple tags, for instance:
'news', 'tech', 'fintech'. I want the user to be able to search by filtering them (so he can select the tags). In postgres the type is a `text[]`. What I tried until now is creating a function that verifies if an array is subarray but I think the types are messed up.

This is how I try to filter:

```py
posts = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.public == True).filter(isSubset(models.Post.tags, ['news', 'tech'] )).all()
```

If I try just the first filter (if it is public), it works, but the second filter gives this error:
TypeError: object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len()

This is the function that verifies the subset:

```py
def isSubset(arr1: List[str], arr2: List[str]):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    if len(arr1) < len(arr2):
        return False
 
    arr1.sort()
    arr2.sort()
 
    while i < len(arr2) and j < len(arr1):
        if arr1[j] < arr2[i]:
            j += 1
        elif arr1[j] == arr2[i]:
            j += 1
            i += 1
        elif arr1[j] > arr2[i]:
            return False
    return False if i < len(arr2) else True
```

I use FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, Pydantic and postgres.

Comment: `models.Post.tags` are not the actual tags for a post - it's an InstrumentedList (as the error tells you) that will get populated for each returned row (.. and instead of implementing sets yourself, Python offers you the `set` built in type). Do you want to return posts with either `news` or `tech`, or posts that have both `news` and `tech`?

Comment: @MatsLindh in this case, both "news" and "tech".

Comment: You might be able to use `.filter(Post.tags.all(['news', 'tech'])` since you have a postgres array type, but I have no experience with using that (and not sure if this is the problem that it solves). However, there's an alternate strategy described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349832/sqlalchemy-filter-to-match-all-instead-of-any-values-in-list